# JavaScript, JQuery. Need help to get the 'name' out of my JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON, that looks like this:

## /subject/create/sample

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "sample",
        "created_by": "Sample96",
        "created_time": "2012-09-10T20:44:11",
        "num_of_followers": 1,
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

Now in my JS, I want to have something like this:

```
function fnClickAddRow(data) {
        $("#s").append(data['name']); //it doesn't work
}
```

Html looks like this:

```
<p id="s">Subject : </p>
```

updated:

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    add_subject_to_subjects_list();
    subject_description();
    data_tables();
});


/* DataTables */
function data_tables() {
    var oTable = $('.book-grid').dataTable({
    });
}

function fnClickAddRow(data) {
    var result = data[0].user_id;
    $("#s").append(result);
}

 
   
/* PERSONAL_PAGE.HTML */


function add_subject_to_subjects_list() {
    show_subjects_list();
    $("#btn-create-subject").click(function() {
        var value = $("#id_name").val();
        var link = "/subject/create/"+value;
        $.post(link, function(data) {
            show_subjects_list();
            fnClickAddRow(data);
        });
    });
}
function show_subjects_list() {
    $("#list").text('');
    $.get("/subject/list/", function(data){
        for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            var subject = data[i]['name'];
            var followers = data[i]['num_of_followers']
        //  var link = "/user/"+username+"/subject/"+subject;
            $("#list")
            .append('<li>'+subject+'<span id="followers"> ['+followers+'] </span></li><br>');
        };
    }, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is `data[0].name` or `data[0]['name']` (both are equal, but `.name` is the more common way) - see the `[]` around your object? That wraps it in an array (which contains only one element, the object that has e.g. the `name` property).

Comment: For some reasons when I do what you suggested, I got nothing, but if I do $("#s").append(data)   I have the whole array returned

Comment: @Serg maybe provide all your code including how you're running it? jsfiddle.com

Comment: Then `data` is not the object you posted. Why not use `console.log(data)` to have a look at it?

Comment: @Nile I just made one: http://jsfiddle.net/sd98n/1/ but I don't really know where to put my JSON

Comment: @Serg I'm not sure what you *think* you're trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/sd98n/6/ works fine. Make sure you're including jQ.

Comment: Fantastic! your example works fine, let me just update my Question, I will post more JS that I have,

Comment: in jsfiddle, it works the way I want, but in my computer unfortunately it doesn't